# FOP hyphenation xsl fo

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop, hyphenation

I would like to use the attribute `hyphenate="true"` on my tag `<subtitle>`, and set `hyphenation="false"` on the `<italic>` elements it may contain. The problem is that I can use the hyphenation only on `fo:block` and `fo:character`. Could someone give me an advice?

This is an example of my xml:

```
<subtitle type="subtitles">
    Some text that should have the hyphenation true 
    (<italic>This one shoud have the hyphenation false</italic>).
</subtitle>
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? What is the content model for `italic` (only text or other elements too)?

Comment: Inside <italic> I have only text. Now I can't use XSLT 2.0, because there are a lot of document, but if it's the only manner I have to do it; do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

`hyphenate` is an inherited property (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#hyphenate).  The text in your XSL-FO is treated as if it was a sequence of `fo:character` FOs (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_character).

Just put `hyphenate="false"` on the `fo:inline` for `italic` and it will have effect on the notional `fo:character` FOs making up the text.

Comment: And remove keep-together="always" because in a conforming processor, this would have the effect of keeping everything inside the italic element together on a single line.

Comment: @Tony Graham Hi, thank you, I have already tried your advise, but doesn't run, because the hyphenation work only on fo:block and fo:character. Kevin Brown Hi Kevin, yes I tried everything like that, but doesn't run for instance keep-with-previous etc...

Comment: I will test BUT you are using FOP. If something that should be supported is not, then report it to them. If you would like to even attempt alternative "hacks" to make it behave, good luck. You could try something like splitting every word in the italic grouplng into an inline that has keep-together.within-line = "always" ... up to you.